# HTML carousel images crops instead of scaling on mobile

Tags: html, css, carousel, scale

I can't get carousel images to scale instead of cropping on mobile version. I tried different solutions from web but non of them worked for me or i did something wrong. Am i just missing something or everything is wrong here?

Here's my html code for carousel:

```
   <header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="carousel-item active img-responsive" href="index3.html" style="background-image: url('img/test2.jpg')" class="img-responsive img-cus">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="color:darkslategray;">
          <h3>Producent kotłów 5 klasy</h3>
          <p>Kocioł z podajnikiem dzięki specjalnym rozwiązaniom pozwala na uzyskanie bezdymnego spalania, niskiej emisji i sprawności co najmniej 89,9 %.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./img/test.jpg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="color:white; ">
          <h3 class="strokeme">Pełen profesjonalizm</h3>
          <p class="strokeme">Działamy na rynku od 29 lat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('./img/test3.jpg')"><a href="index3.html">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="color:red;">
          <h3>Szeroka oferta</h3>
          <p>Posiadamy kompletną ofertę kotłów według nowych norm</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

and here is css:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Really need more info... complete styles sheet, javascript etc. Do you have a working sample? What's the URL?

Comment: The `.carousel-item` css class is just one part of the carousel display. Can you please provide more?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the vh, which means it will automatically scale so the image will fill things veritcally, but not care about the sides. Try setting the vw (view width) on the image to 100%